# Как сделать бокс?

Tags: html, javascript

Как сделать бокс, которому присваивается ссылка, которую юзер вводит в инпут бокс ниже, при этом ссылка сохраняется для этого пользователя при повторном посещении страницы?

Answer (score 1):

Пример ниже (на основе JQuery cookie plugin) сохраняет в куки значение, вводимое пользователем в поле ввода в обозреватель. Его несложно расширить на несколько полей ввода.

HTML:

```
<input name="something" type="text" />
```

JQuery:

```
$('[name=something]').each(
    function() {
        // Восстановить из куки
        var name = $(this).attr('name');
        if ($.cookie(name)) {
            $(this).val($.cookie(name));
        }

        // Сохранить в куки
        $(this).change(
            function() {
                $.cookie(name, $(this).val(), { path: '/', expires: 7 });
            }
        );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

5 раз перечитал, ничего не понял :(
Попробуйте перефразировать вопрос.

Не совсем уверен, но мне кажется что речь про html и javascript и что нужно чтото сохранить.
Если это так, то как вариант, вы можете сохранять данные в cookie посредством javascript или же на стороне сервера (php,java,asp, etc)